# Improving the algorithm to distinguish the different types of table

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have two tables with the following structures where in table 1, the ID is next to Name while in table 2, the ID is next to Title 1. The one similarity between the two tables are that, the first person always has the ID next to their name. They are different for the subsequent people.

Table 1:

```
Name&Title   | ID # 
----------------------
Random_Name 1|2000 
Title_1_1    | - 
Title_1_2    | -
Random_Name 2| 2000
Title_2_1    | -
Title_2_2    | -
...          |...
```

Table 2:

```
Name&Title   | ID # 
----------------------
Random_Name 1| 2000 
Title_1_1    | -
Title_1_2    | -
Random_Name 2| -
Title_2_1    | 2000
Title_2_2    | -
...          |...
```

I have the code to recognize table 1 but struggle to incorporate structure 2. The table is stored as a nested list of row (each row is a list). Usually, for one person there are only 1 row of name but multiple rows of titles. The pseudo-code is this:

```
set count = 0
find the ID next to the first name, set it to be a recognizer
for row_i,row in enumerate(table):
   compare the ID of the next row until I found: row[1] == recognizer
   set count = row i
   slice the table to get the first person.
```

The actual code is this:

```
    header_ind = 0 # something related to the rest of the code
    recognizer = data[header_ind+1][1]
    count = header_ind+1
    result = []
    result.append(data[0]) #this append the headers
    for i, row in enumerate(data[header_ind+2:]):
        if i <= len(data[header_ind+4:]):
            if row[1] and data[i+1+header_ind+2][1] is recognizer:
                print data[i+header_ind+3]
                one_person = data[count:i+header_ind+3]
                result.append(one_person)
                count = i+header_ind+3
        else:
            if i == len(data[header_ind+3:]):
                last_person = data[count:i+header_ind+3]
                result.append(last_person)
                count = i+header_ind+3
```

I have been thinking about this for a while and so I just want to know whether it is possible to get an algorithm to incorporate Table 2 given that the we cannot distinguish the row name and titles.

Comment: Are you using a dictionary to make table1? If so, you can make table2 inside this loop to be created as a list of elements concatenating `i` and `row` together.

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't make any sense. It's not clear what the algorithm is trying to do at all. What's a "recognizer?" Anyway why can't you simply iterate through the table twice (once for each column), throw away the non-relevant entries and pick out the names into separate lists?

Comment: @SebasSBM I dont think I understand your approach. But I can create it as a dictionary. Say I want to find the of the index `i` of row  Random_Name 1 and the index `i` of row Random_Name 2. How does it work?

Comment: @aestrivex For many reasons, I can't recognize names and titles separately. For example, if I go through table2 and throw away all empty entries in **column ID**, I will lose Random_Name 2. And also, _recognizer_ is the original ID (something like gender or birth year). each person in these two tables will have this same ID. However, it is kept in different row for them.

Comment: Why would you "lose" empty entries? Does the problem also come with the constraint that you can never iterate through the array more than once? If so, why?

Comment: @aestrivex: I can iterate as many times as I can. What I mean is that I dont really understand how you throw away the non-relevant entries (if you throw the relevant entries, how do you keep the structure) ? What would be an example of the non-relevant entries here?

Comment: As I said, just copy the entries you want (i.e. the names and the IDs) from each column into separate lists and ignore the other entries. If you still can't understand then sorry I don't have more time to help you.

Comment: @aestrivex I see what you saying, but the problem with table2 is that I have no way of knowing which are names and which are titles. It is like I have no way of knowing which entries are relevant in column **Name** of table2. (For table 1, I use the ID to find the names). For example, I dont know if Title_1_2 is a name or a title. And also, the number of rows of titles varies for each person. Say person 3 might have 3 title rows but person 2 only have 2 title rows. Even though i want the names, I can't copy it to another list. Does it make senses?

Comment: Trying to work on a relational model with restrictions on only using Two dimensional arrays ? it's possible but what if a third table comes along with ID on a different row ?

Comment: @Superfy Can you explain how on using the relational model? There should only be two tables. Table 1 where Id are next to names and Table 2 where ID are next to title_1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to stick this here

So these are your inputs assumption is you are restricted to this...:

```
# Table 1 
data1 = [['Name&Title','ID#'],
    ['Random_Name1','2000'],
    ['Title_1_1','-'],
    ['Title_1_2','-'],
    ['Random_Name2','2000'],
    ['Title_2_1','-'],
    ['Title_2_2','-']]

# TABLE 2
data2 = [['Name&Title','ID#'],
    ['Random_Name1','2000'],
    ['Title_1_1','-'],
    ['Title_1_2','-'],
    ['Random_Name2','-'],
    ['Title_2_1','2000'],
    ['Title_2_2','-']]
```

And this is your desired output:

```
for x in data: 
    print x

['Random_Name2', '2000']
['Name&Title', 'ID#']
[['Random_Name1', '2000'], ['Title_1_1', '-'], ['Title_1_2', '-']]
[['Random_Name2', '2000'], ['Title_2_1', '-'], ['Title_2_2', '-']]
```

Comment: Hi, yeah. .That is my desire output. So how do you go from assumption to there?

Comment: It's a doozy.. if there is nothing that is unique between title and Random_name I don't think it would be possible - if there is perhaps look at that to identify the start of a persons record... until you have the odd ball person named Mr, Mrs etc.... or if you know for certain the pattern you can build that in as a condition but it won't be automated.

Comment: if you are still interested in what I do, I found another way to find a list of names and match them. So I actually could not find a solution to this problem. sadly.

Comment: This problem cannot have an elgant solution unless you know the value of random names and or the titles before hand... And then only if they do not cross over.